# How do I find all users logged in with Server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003

I want to know whether it will affect users if I reboot my server? Can I find out who is currently logged on to my Windows Server 2003?

Comment: did you mean reboot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Computer Management -> Shared Folders -> Sessions

This will show current users logged in users to any Shares (Printers/Mapped Drives/Etc).  Then I usually check Open Files and notify those users.

Comment: If you're talking about workstation authentication... then there's no way to tell from the server who is logged in.  You must go to each workstation (or write a script to do it for you) and look at the "LOGONSERVER" environment variable.  Rebooting a server won't force users to log off though.

Answer (score 1):

From command line use qwinsta for query and rwinsta to remove user sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see [How Can I List Open Sessions and Open Files on a Computer?](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/02/16/how-can-i-list-open-sessions-and-open-files-on-a-computer.aspx)

If it is a DC the effect will be that users cannot authenticate to that DC until it's back up (that may or may not be an issue depending on your environment)

Answer (score 0):

For remotely checking who is currently logged in [PsLoggedOn](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897545.aspx) is a great tool.

Example: Psloggedon \\ComputerName/IPaddress